# Fetching balance for Monero Wallet with getBalance function in JavaScript doesn't work. I am using RPC method for it. Output: Showing HTTP/ error

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc

```
const publicKey = req.body;
try {
    //connect to daemon
    let daemon = await monerojs.connectToDaemonRpc("http://localhost:28081", "pinkumonero", "1234");
    let height = await daemon.getHeight();
    console.log("Height is:", height);
    
    const response = axios.post("http://localhost:28082",
        publicKey,
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        }).then((responseData) => {
            dataFetched = responseData.data;
            console.log("Result of fetching balance", dataFetched);
            res.status(200).json({ Balance: dataFetched });
        })

} catch (err) {
    console.log("Error in fetching balance of XMR", err);
    res.status(500).json({ StatusCode: "0", Message: "Error in XMR balance fetching", error: err.message })
}
```

})

Comment: Using curl command in the CLI [curl http://127.0.0.1:28082/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_balance","params":{"account_index":0,"address_indices":[0,1]}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json']

Comment: curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed    ===>This error appears